# What is the role of B-field $B \in H^2(X,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ in mathematics?

Tags: mirror-symmetry

In mirror symmetry conjecture, we add what is called "B-field" $B \in H^2(X,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ in the Kähler moduli space so that the Kähler moduli space has enough freedom comparable to the complex moduli space of a mirror manifold. In string theory, one may twist the Lagrangian by this auxiliary 2-form $B$.

The usual Kähler moduli space parametrizes the volume of 2-cycles. Naively $B$ parametrizes the imaginary volume of the cycles, but is this really a useful concept? What is the role of B-field in mathematics?

Comment: In what sort of mathematics?  The $B$-field can have many roles, dpeend on context.

Comment: @userN: I thought the OPs mention of mirror symmetry was specific enough. My thesis was supposed to have applications to mirror symmetry so I read some things about it and could never figure out if the $B$ field played any other role than to complexify the Kahler cone in a managable way. It always seemed like a parameter we add just because we can.

Comment: @GunnarMagnusson  Perhaps the OP is looking for connections to other parts of mathematics?  The mirror symmetry B-field is a cohomological shadow of more complicated objects.

Comment: Yes, I am wondering if B-filed plays any role in other fileds of mathematics. It seems to me that it is added just to make the dimension of the moduli spaces the same.

Comment: Twisted K-theory, higher gauge theory to name a couple. See also http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kalb-Ramond+field

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28541/complexified-kahler-form.